# Multiple entries on an e-visitor 651 visa

Tags: visa, australia

does the term "travel facility: multiple" mean that I can enter Australia several times over a 12 month period?

Comment: Yes, that does mean multiple entries. It goes on with the stay period entry which says "3 month(s) from the date of **each** arrival.

Answer (score 1):

The [Australia eVisitor (subclass 651)](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/651-) allows multiple entries, with each visit no more than 3 months duration (added emphasis mine).

> Your eVisitor lets you:
>
> - **enter Australia for up to three months during each visit during the 12 months from the date the eVisitor is granted**
> - have a holiday or visit family and friends in Australia
> - study in Australia for up to three months in some circumstances
> - engage in business visitor activities while in Australia provided you:
>
>   - do not work for or provide services to, a business or organisation
>   - do not sell goods or services to the public.
>
> Business visitor activities include:
>
> - making general business or employment enquiries
> - investigating, negotiating, signing or reviewing a business contract
> - activities carried out as part of an official government-to-government visit
> - participating in conferences, trade fairs or seminars, as long as you are not being paid by the organisers for you participation.
>
> Volunteer work tourism schemes
>
> In general, an eVisitor does not allow you to work in Australia. However, you might be able to work as a volunteer if:
>
> - your main purpose in visiting Australia is tourism and the voluntary work is incidental to tourism
> - the work is genuinely voluntary and you are not paid for it, other than for meals, accommodation or out of pocket living expenses
> - the work would not otherwise be done in return for wages by an Australian resident